# Array slice for specific keys

Tags: php

Is there built-in function, or shorter way to extract elements into new array, as described here?

```
<?php

function arr_slice ($arr, $keys) {
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($keys as $k) { $ret[$k] = $arr[$k]; }

  return $ret;
}

$array = array(
  "a" => 1,
  "b" => 2,
  "c" => 3,
  "d" => 4,
);
print_r(
  arr_slice($array, array("b", "d"))
);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [b] => 2
    [d] => 4
)
```

Comment: Is there a particular rule to define which keys are outputted?  If there is just use array_filter?

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull wanted keys are `array("b", "d")`

Comment: [array_intersect_key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) perhaps?

Comment: @MarkBaker looks close enough https://eval.in/293029

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `array_intersect_key` but you need a hash table as a second argument.

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($array, array("b"=>"", "d"=>"")));
Array
(
    [b] => 2
    [d] => 4
)
```

Comment: `array_flip(array("b", "d"));` or `array_flip(['b', 'd'])` is even easier to read for the second argument

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own function that accepts an array of keys as parameter and then make it as an hashtable in order to use `array_intersect_key`

```
function getByKeys($array, $keys)
{
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
}
```